# Recursively set file attributes

Tags: powershell

This code:

```
Get-ChildItem $targetConfig -Recurse | Set-ItemProperty -Name IsReadOnly -Value $false
```

Returns several errors:

> Set-ItemProperty : Property System.Boolean IsReadOnly=False does not
>   exist. At line:1 char:56
>   + Get-ChildItem $targetConfig -Recurse | Set-ItemProperty <<<<  -Name IsReadOnly -Value $false
>       + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (System.Boolean IsReadOnly=False:PSNoteProperty) [Set-ItemProperty], IOException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetPropertyError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetItemPropertyCommand

What this errors means?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It happens because:

```
Get-ChildItem $targetConfig -Recurse
```

Return both DirectoryInfo and FileInfo. And Set-ItemProperty fails on setting "ReadOnly" for DirectoryInfo.

To handle this use:

```
Get-ChildItem $targetConfig -Recurse |
    Where-Object {$_.GetType().ToString() -eq "System.IO.FileInfo"} |
    Set-ItemProperty -Name IsReadOnly -Value $false
```

Comment: A schort condition can be: `where { -not $_.psiscontainer }`. in Powershell V3 just add the `-File` switch to `getchilditem`.